# Do the cutime and cstime jiffies include the child processes as well?

Tags: linux, proc, stat

In the file `/proc/[PID]/stat`, the values `cutime` and `cstime` (14 and 15 elements of that file) are jiffies with childs, does that mean the childs of a process?

```
int     cutime;                   /** user mode jiffies with childs **/
int     cstime;                   /** kernel mode jiffies with childs **/
```

Does that mean the jiffies are also including the children of the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cutime and cstime meaning is documented in `man 5 proc`

> cutime
>
> Amount  of  time  that this process’s waited-for children have been scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks...
>
> cstime
>
> Amount  of time that this process’s waited-for children have been scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks...

`utime` and `stime` measure CPU time of the process without children that the process created.

`cutime` and `cstime` are sum of CPU times of all children (and their children...) that the process created. It does not include `utime` and `stime` of this process but children only time.

Note that `utime` and `ctime` are updated online when the process uses CPU but `cutime` and `cstime` are updated when a child exits and the process calls `wait` for this child.

EDIT - an experiment for @txs because @txs does not believe:

Simple script for showing proc statistics:

```
$ cat ./procstat.sh 6668
while sleep 1
do
   cat /proc/$1/stat | awk '{ print "utime:", $14, "stime:", $15, "cutime:" $16, "cstime:", $17 }'
done
```

Two terminals, one is running the script and the other one executes time consuming processing. I measured a bash process. I started an infinite loop in the measured bash. utime was constantly increased. Then I interrupted the loop and start a child bash process and run the infinite loop in child process. Nothing changed but the cutime was changed at once when I interrupted the process and exit the child bash.

```
 $ ps                           +
   PID TTY          TIME CMD    |
 10178 pts/2    00:00:00 bash   |
 10197 pts/2    00:00:00 ps     |
                                |  $ ./procstat.sh 10178
                                |  utime: 2 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 2 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 2 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 3 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 3 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 3 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 $ while true; do true; done    |  utime: 49 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 137 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 209 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 296 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 391 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 ^C                             |  utime: 477 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 521 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 521 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 521 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 $ bash                         |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 $ while true; do true; done    |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 ^C                             |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:1 cstime: 3
 $ exit                         |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:623 cstime: 6
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:623 cstime: 6
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:623 cstime: 6
                                |  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:623 cstime: 6
                                +  utime: 522 stime: 1 cutime:623 cstime: 6
```

Comment: I'm confused when you say the utime and stime measure the CPU time of the process without children. From the kernel code for example linux/v4.4.144/source/kernel/sys.c#L884 and linux/v4.4.144/source/kernel/sched/cputime.c#L286, the utime and stime are sum values of tasks which were being added up using a for_each_thread loop. If the tasks are threads, and the task group is the process, and assume the children created by the process are the threads for the process, then the utime and stime indeed include the children. It appears what you said is wrong?https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.144

Comment: I think the question was about child process and not about thread groups. I am not an expert for cputime source but I think it iterates over threads in the same thread group. That mean it iterates over all threads belong to the process but it does not calculate child processes.

Comment: NOTE:
The Linux kernel does not provide any special scheduling semantics or data structures to represent threads. Instead, a thread is merely a process that shares certain resources with other processes. Each thread has a unique task_struct and appears to the kernel as a normal process (which just happens to share resources, such as an address space, with other processes).

Comment: Actually this link is helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364660/are-threads-implemented-as-processes-on-linux

Comment: Well yes, threads and processes are similar from kernel point of view. It was especially valid for early linux thread implementation in the kernel 2.4.x. It was tricky to recognize what is a thread and and what is a process in 90's. But nowadays the `proc stat` actually provides statistics per process. So utime is really time spent by all threads of a process with given pid. And cutime is really time spent by all threads in all (process) children.